# AS3 : FLASH DESKTOP APP THAT CAN DOWNLOAD FROM WEBSITE

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was planned to make a game for pharmacy's student. it will play on desktop. but i really didn't have any experience to make an application that can be download from server. I was planned to make it 2 level first. but when people want more level, they need to download from my website. if it's possible, can anyone give me a link or some thing that i can study for this. please give me some reference for this kind. thank you very much :)

Comment: I think that you want to publish your game using Adobe AIR, which will produce a desktop program. Same AS3 code (mostly) as Flash running in browsers. It's not clear if your lack of experience is in programming or just in getting an .exe downloaded. What do you say?

Comment: yes you are right. I am gone make it on adobe air. but i want to have some reference about, when my app is finish, i just make it 2 level, so, i want the other lever downloaded from my web ? how about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your asking for can be a complicated procedure.  The basics of getting information from a web-server is using an URLLoader.  You can reference Adobe's URLLoader reference from this link.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

In order for this process to work, you need to make your levels into files that can be downloaded and used within your application.  They can be as simple as XML or JSON documents, or as complicated as SWF's.  This will have to be up to you to decide the best way to handle creating new levels.